# Android bluetooth: how to poll for connections/disconnections

Tags: android, bluetooth

I need to continuously poll for getting bluetooth devices connections/disconnections in my activity to update a listView with the currenctly available devices.
I use btAdapter.startDiscovery() but it is not permanent ... how can i correctly get the on/off events for the devices?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a broadcastreceiver to listen for the specific events you are talking about.  You could even fire off another discovery mode after it comes out of its current discovery mode to have it keep scanning

```
BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED
BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED
```

You can use the intent extra's to be able to get the name (ect) from the device that connects
I would read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html and 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html